# Book on the first-order modal logic

Tags: reference-request, first-order-logic, modal-logic

Is there a book on the metatheory for the first-order modal logic, or do I just need to take FOL as a base and use the [standard translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_translation)?

Comment: Nino Cocchiarella & Max Freund, *Modal Logic: An Introduction to Its Syntax and Semantics*, Oxford UP, 2008.

Comment: Can you make a full answer, telling more about that book? I don't feel like spending more than $40 on a book that was recommended to me in the comments :)

Comment: Search on Google Books : you can read the Table of Contents and browse a portion of it :)

Comment: A brief overview, with bibliography, in *SEP* entry on [Modal Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/); you may try with the most up-to-date books : Hughes & Cresswell, *A New Introduction to Modal Logic* (1996), R.Goldblatt, *Mathematics of Modality* (1993), M.Fitting & R.Mendelsohn, *First Order Modal Logic* (1998).

Comment: This is worthy of a full answer, an upvote and the "accepted answer" status :)

Comment: @user132181: The standard translation only works for propositional modal logic (and it translates these formulas into first-order, non-modal, formulas). Thus, right now I am afraid that your question does not make sense: could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D. M. Gabbay & V. B. Shehtman & D. P. Skvortsov. *Quantification in Nonclassical Logic* (2009) (Series: Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics, Volume 153. Elsevier)
It covers a lot of material on first-order modal and first-order intuitionistic logic. E.g. Kripke semantics, algebraic semantics, completeness, etc. Don't be misguided with the titles of the Chapters in the book: "Chapter 1. Basic propositional logic" and "Chapter 2. Basic predicate logic" both mean modal and (super-)intuitionistic logics (propositional ones in Ch.1 and predicate ones in Ch.2).

Comment: That sounds very interesting, I'm definitely going to check it out.